# What is character in all table cells except bottom right cell?

Tags: tables, characters

And how do I get rid of them?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{font={tt,Large}}
\caption*{Summertime Checklist}
\begin{tabularx}{262pt}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\toprule     &
\texttt{Mo.} &
\texttt{Tu.} &
\texttt{We.} &
\texttt{Th.} &
\texttt{Fr.} &
\texttt{Sa.} &
\texttt{Su.}
\\ 
\midrule
\texttt{GO FISHING} &
| &| &| &| &| &| &| &
\\
\midrule
\texttt{GO CAMPING} &
| &| &| &| &| &| &
\\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here's my MikTex/pdfLatex output

[image: Table]

Comment: it is the `|` character which typesets as a dash in the eccentric encoding (OT1) used by the default computer modern fonts. As shown in the answer below you should specify rules in the table preamble (where `|` is a syntax character to specify a rule, not just a character being typeset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{font={tt,Large}}
\caption*{Summertime Checklist}
\begin{tabularx}{262pt}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\toprule     &
\texttt{Mo.} &
\texttt{Tu.} &
\texttt{We.} &
\texttt{Th.} &
\texttt{Fr.} &
\texttt{Sa.} &
\texttt{Su.}
\\ 
\midrule

\texttt{GO FISHING} &&&&&&&&\\

\midrule

\texttt{GO CAMPING} &&&&&&&&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```